# Ruby class << Klass = Module::new

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, idioms, eigenclass

I have across the following syntax in a code snippet, and I'm not sure what it does.

```
class << PushableModule = Module::new
 def new *args, &blk
   m = Module::new( *args, &blk )
   m.extend Pushable
   m
 end
end
```

First off, the class or module `PushableModule` doesn't exist in the file/program, and secondly what appears to be happening is that I'm retrieving its eigenclass and then setting it equal to `Module::new` prior to defining a block, which I just don't understand. Could someone please explain this to me (as well as what the code snippet actually does)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are taking the operator precedence wrong. It means

```
class << (PushableModule = Module::new)
  ...
end
```

It creates a module by `Module::new`, then names it as `PushableModule`, then opens its eigenclass by `<<`.

It is overwriting the constructor of `PushableModule`. Since `new` should be defined as `PushableModule.new`, not as an instance method, the definition is done within the eigenclass.

Usually, you don't overwrite `new`, but define an instance method `initialize`, but in some special occasions, the `new` constructor can be rewritten.